# Can't find C:\Android\tools\bin\platform-tools

Tags: android, windows, react-native

I'm trying to install react native on windows and I'm following this guide https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup (you have to select "React Native CLI Quickstart" then "Windows" as Development OS and "Android" as Target OS)

I have done everything but I can't seem to find the platform file at C:\Android\tools\bin\platform-tools (4th point of the guide)

the bin folder: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Hkoi.jpg

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the image

Platform tools can be found under C:\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

No need to go inside tools folder

Answer (score 0):

Mine were in this location:

`C:\Users\{user_name}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`